# My app keeps stopping when I populate my last field. No errors in code to review

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an app for a homework assignment with a workout class that will calculate how many calories are burned based on how much time is spent doing certain workouts.  I have my layout like I want it, and the emulator runs fine until I enter the last(third) input in.  I am still a rookie at this and I'm sure my error is simple.  Any help is much appreciated!!!

Here is my Workout Class:

```
    public class Workout {

        private int totalCalories;
        private float runningTime;
        private float cyclingTime;
        private float walkingTime;

        public Workout( float r, float w, float c){

            setRunning(r);
            setWalking(w);
            setCycling(c);

        }

        public void setRunning(float r)
        {
            runningTime=r;
        }
        public void setCycling(float c)
        {
            cyclingTime=c;
        }

        public void setWalking(float w)
        {
            walkingTime = w;
        }

        public float caloriesBurned(){
            return runningTime * 350 + walkingTime * 100 + cyclingTime * 50;
        }
    }
```

And here is my MainActivity class:

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private Workout calCalc;
        private EditText runEditText;
        private EditText walkEditText;
        private EditText cycleEditText;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            calCalc=new Workout(150.0f, 100.0f, 50.0f );
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            runEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount_run);
            walkEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount_walk);
            cycleEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount_cycle);

            TextChangeHandler tch = new TextChangeHandler();
            runEditText.addTextChangedListener(tch);
            walkEditText.addTextChangedListener(tch);
            cycleEditText.addTextChangedListener(tch);
        }

        public void calculate() {
            String runString = runEditText.getText().toString();
            String walkString = walkEditText.getText().toString();
            String cycleString = cycleEditText.getText().toString();

            TextView caloriesBurnedTextView =
                    (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount_calories);

            try{

                float runAmount = Integer.parseInt(runString);
                float walkAmount = Integer.parseInt(walkString);
                float cycleAmount = Integer.parseInt(cycleString);


                calCalc.setRunning(150.0f * runAmount);
                calCalc.setWalking(100.0f * walkAmount);
                calCalc.setCycling(50.0f * cycleAmount);

                float totalCalories = calCalc.caloriesBurned();

                caloriesBurnedTextView.setText((int) totalCalories);

            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {

            }
        }

        private class TextChangeHandler implements TextWatcher
        {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable e) {
                calculate();
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {

            }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int after)
            {

            }
        }

    }
```

Once the 3 fields for running, walking, and cycling are entered there is a "calculate" button that is clicked to make the calculation and output the total calories burned.

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2.MainActivity">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_run"
            style="@style/LabelStyle"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:text="@string/label_run"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/amount_run"
            style="@style/InputStyle"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label_run"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/label_run"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:hint="@string/amount_run_hint"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_walk"
            style="@style/LabelStyle"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/label_run"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/label_run"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/label_run"
            android:text="@string/label_walk"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/amount_walk"
            style="@style/InputStyle"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label_walk"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/label_walk"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/amount_run"
            android:hint="@string/amount_walk_hint"
            android:inputType="number"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_cycle"
            style="@style/LabelStyle"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/label_walk"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/label_walk"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/label_walk"
            android:text="@string/label_cycle"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/amount_cycle"
            style="@style/InputStyle"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label_cycle"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/label_cycle"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/amount_walk"
            android:hint="@string/amount_cycle_hint"
            android:inputType="number"/>


        <!-- red line -->

        <View
            android:id="@+id/red_line"
            android:layout_below="@+id/label_cycle"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_height="5dip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/label_run"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/amount_run"
            android:background="#FF00"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_calories"
            style="@style/LabelStyle"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/red_line"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/label_run"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/label_run"
            android:text="@string/label_calories"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amount_calories"
            style="@style/OutputStyle"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/label_calories"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label_calories"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/amount_run"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/amount_run"/>



        <Button
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/amount_calories"
            android:text="@string/button_calculate"
            android:onClick="calculate"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Logcat after correcting the catch:

```
2019-04-14 10:25:59.830 946-946/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-04-14 10:25:59.832 946-946/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-04-14 10:26:00.057 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2-2/lib/x86
2019-04-14 10:26:00.076 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2019-04-14 10:26:00.232 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:22)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.294 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2-2/split_
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:22)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.295 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.427 946-957/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 13699(1168KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 11.367ms total 31.707ms
2019-04-14 10:26:00.491 946-962/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-04-14 10:26:00.491 946-962/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-04-14 10:26:00.491 946-962/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-04-14 10:26:00.491 946-962/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-04-14 10:26:00.507 946-962/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x96cce4e0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2019-04-14 10:26:00.528 946-962/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x96cce4e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa535d8c0)
2019-04-14 10:26:00.567 946-946/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
2019-04-14 10:26:00.573 946-962/com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x96cce4e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa535d8c0)
```

Comment: post stacktrace.

Comment: Can you post XML file as well other than the error logcat?

Comment: XML file has been added.

Comment: try to change the `catch` as follow: `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` and post the logcat please

Comment: when the app crashed ?

Answer (score 0):

> Process: com.jblearning.caloriesburnedcal2, PID: 436
>       android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xfde8

You cannot `setText` to Int. You need to convert totalCalories to String before `setText`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement  "there is a "calculate" button that is clicked to make the calculation and output the total calories burned."

Implement calculate() method on click of button, instead of afterTextChanged().

And if problem still persist, please add logs as requested in comments.